# Undefined variable in phpstorm using laravel . Controller & blade template are provided

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm getting this error message for my code:

> Undefined variable: questions (View:
>   home/xxxx/PhpstormProjects/xxxxx/resources/views/home.blade.php)

Please, try to shed some light on what could be wrong. 
I have provided my `QuestionController` & question template. Not sure, what my code is missing. Here is my code:

```
    QuestionController:

    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Question;

class QuestionController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function show(Question $question)
    {

        return view('question')->with('question', $question);
    }



    question.blade.php

    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Question</div>

                    <div class="card-body">

                        {{$question->body}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary float-right"
                           href="#">
                            Edit Question
                        </a>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header"><a class="btn btn-primary `float-left"`
                                                href="#">
                            Answer Question
                        </a></div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        @forelse($question->answers as $answer)
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">{{$answer->body}}`</div>`
                                <div class="card-footer">

                                    <a class="btn btn-primary float-right"
                                       href="#">
                                        View
                                    </a>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @empty
                            <div class="card">

                                <div class="card-body"> No Answers</div>
                            </div>
                        @endforelse


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
@endsection


home.blade.php

    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Questions


                        <div class="card-body">

                            <div class="card-deck">
                                @foreach($questions as $question)
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                                        <div class="card mb-3 ">
                                            <div class="card-header">
                                                <small class="text-muted">
                                                    Updated: {{ $question->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
                                                    Answers: {{ $question->answers()->count() }}

                                                </small>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <p class="card-text">{{$question->body}}</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-footer">
                                                <p class="card-text">

                                                    <a class="btn btn-primary float-right" href="{{ route('question.show', ['id' => $question->id]) }}">
                                                        View
                                                    </a>
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                @endforeach
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <div class="float-right">
                                {{ $questions->links() }}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: You're using a variable `$questions` somewhere in your `home` template but you're not passing it to the view. Here: `{{ $questions->links() }}`

Comment: Just provided my home template. I've been trying to locate but having trouble.

Comment: Is there a $questions variable in your home.blade file? The error does not appear to be in the code provided.

Comment: man, once u use question as string once question as array

Comment: @foreach($questions as $question) i have i nmy home template

Comment: @devk excuse me, the code you provided is already in my home template so unfortunately getting same error

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. You're referencing a variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: @devk That's where iam getting confused. Is there something in my QuestionController in which I can update to have code work or is probl in home template?

Comment: @GoogleMac Just provided my home template and yes that variable is there..any ideas? -Thanks

Comment: The problem is in your home template. Pass it a paginated result of questions in a variable named `$questions` and it will all work.

Comment: @devk Here is the code I inserted:

Comment: @devk at foreach ($questions as $question)
        {{ $question->name }} and no luck

Comment: @AdamKozlowski not sure why this isn't working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The first think that comes to my mind is that you are giving a variable named `question` to your view in your controller and you are trying to use `$questions` in your foreach when it must be `$question as $q`

The other thing is that you may want to pass all Questions rows you have to you view, it can be accomplished (this may not be the best solution) by editing your `AppServiceProvider.php`

You have to add this.

```
use View;
use App\Question;

public function boot()
{
    //
    View::share('questions',Question::all());
}
```

But if you do this, it will share the rows obtained with all your views.

hope this helps.